# Remove unknown unicode character from textfiles - sed, other bash/shell methods

Tags: sed, wildcards, perl, replace, file-search

I need to search and replace all occurences of an unknown character in some files having the same name.

Opening such files with vi, I read <91> code for that character.
Opening them with nano, I read a "question mark" in a diamond (black rhumble).

I would like to replace such unknown character with a quote ('). I'm trying many ways with no luck.

I tried:

```
find ./ -name filename.txt -exec perl -i~ -pe "s/\x91/'/" {} \;



find ./ -name filename.txt -exec sed -i "s/\x91/'/g" {} \;
```

**EDIT**
More info on the character:

```
Hexadecimal: 91 68 74 74
Decimal: 145 104 116 116
Octal: 221 150 164 164
Binary: 10010001 01101000 01110100 01110100

LC_ALL=C sed -n l < file

\221
```

If you need more, ask!

Comment: In which way does `sed -i "s/\x91/'/g"` on that `file` not work?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look using `hexdump -C` and find the bytes around it.  Presuming UTF-8, what `vi` shows as `<91>` (decimal 145, a unicode point meaningless in text) would be two bytes, 0xc2 and 0x91.

It's implied your substitutions didn't work at all, but if what you did was just replace 0x91 with 0x27, you'll have invalidated the UTF-8 (the second byte of a two byte sequence always has the high bit set, i.e. is >= 0x80).  This might complicate your analysis, although `vi` should then show it as `?'`.

That said, I tested this and it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

my $data = "";
my $file = $ARGV[0];

while (<>) {
    s/\xc2\x91/'/g;
    $data .= $_;
}

open my $out, '>', $file || die "Could not write $file.";
print $out $data;
close $out;
```

If `$ARGV[0]` exists when `<>` is referenced, perl pops this off the argument stack and takes it as a filepath to use for input (I find short scripts easier to tweak and work with than one liners, BTW).  This accumulates in memory (fine as long as the files are not massive), whereas `perl -i` renames the original file to avoid edit-in-place race conditions (see `perldoc perlrun`).

So you could use that:

```
  find . -name "*.txt" -exec whatever.pl {} +
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the question mark remains...

Comment: Did you check it in `hexdump -C` to see what's actually there?

Answer (score 3):

If it is indeed the character U+0091 (0xc2 0x91 in UTF-8 encoding) and not the byte 0x91, then:

```
PERLIO=:utf8 perl -pi -e "s/\N{U+0091}/'/g" file
```

Would convert it to `'`.

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/\xc2\x91/'/" file
```

**Edit:**

However, in your case, the file is not in UTF-8. UTF-8 characters are one byte, only for ASCII characters (for values 0 to 0x7F). The other characters are represented by two or more bytes whose value is greater than `0x7F`. So a `0x91` byte, with no byte greater than 0x7F around it cannot be found in a utf-8 file.

More likely, your file is in a single-byte character set, most likely some Microsoft one like [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

In windows-1252, 0x91 is the left single quote character. The unicode equivalent is U+2018 which in UTF-8 is written `0xe2 0x80 0x98`.

If you want to convert your file to UTF-8, best is probably to use a dedicated tool for that. Like:

```
recode windows-1252..utf8 < file
```

Or:

```
iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 < file
```

Or if you want to do it for every `filename.txt`:

```
find . -type f -name filename.txt -exec sh -Cc '
  for file do
    mv "$file" "$file~" &&
      iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 < "$file~" > "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the question mark remains...

Comment: @jasmines Then it's not a `U+0091`. Please add the output of `LC_ALL=C sed -n l < file` to the question.

Comment: it seems to be \221

Comment: I can't convert because is not a single file... I need to batch and recursively search and replace.